# Image added to one node of a networkx graph is not displayed

Tags: python, networkx

I tried adding a jpg image to one specific node of the graph. There is no error, but the image is not displayed in the node. The node I am attempting to ad an image is "KCT BS".

```
img=mpimg.imread('kctbs.jpg')
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(('KCT BS'),attr_dict={'image':'img'}) #added the image to the node named #KCTBS
G.add_edges_from([("KCT BS","Placements"),("KCT BS","Courses"),("KCT BS","Faculty"),("KCT BS","Students"),("Faculty","Core:21")],length=100)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, scale=10)
nx.draw(G,with_labels=True,pos=pos,node_size=500, node_color='r')
# G.node.items(0)
G.nodes['KCT BS']['image']=img
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't draw an image as a node in networkx. But you can draw an image over the node on its position [by matplotlib](https://gist.github.com/munthe/7de513dc886917860f7b960a51c95e10):

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread('hex.png')
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('KCT BS')
G.add_node('WAKA')
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, scale=10)
nx.draw(
    G,
    with_labels=True,
    pos=pos,
    node_size=500,
    node_color='r'
)

ax = plt.gca()
fig = plt.gcf()
trans = ax.transData.transform
trans2 = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform
imsize = 0.1

(x,y) = pos['KCT BS']
xx,yy = trans((x, y))
xa,ya = trans2((xx, yy))
a = plt.axes([xa-imsize/2.0, ya-imsize/2.0, imsize, imsize])
a.imshow(img)
a.set_aspect('equal')
a.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

It will draw a normal networkx graph (with circles as nodes) and then draw your picture on top of the existing graph picture (note that if you have transparent picture like mine, you will see the original networkx node under it).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping out. Also, may I know why my method did not work?

Comment: Because networkx doesn't support custom images for nodes drawing. P.S. If my answer helped you, I will be appreciated if you will accept it.

Comment: The answer was really helpful. Thank you for the sample code